# Retrieving non-zero columns from pandas dataframe as dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given a dataframe like below

```
            cat        dog        hamster    dolphin
cat         1          0.5        0          0.25
dog         0.5        1          0          0
hamster     0          0          1          0.5
dolphin     0.25       0          0.5        1
```

I want to get the column values which are bigger than zero for the given row in dictionary format. For example, for hamster line, the result should be:

```
{ 'hamster': 1, 'dolphin': 0.5 }
```

It would be even better omitting the column with the same name though, so for 'hamster', this would be better:

```
{ 'dolphin': 0.5 }
```

At the moment I receive all values of the given row using `df["hamster"].to_dict()` and removing zero values with dictionary comprehension, like `{k: v for (k,v) in d.items() if v > 0 }`, but it's far from ideal, as in the original size of dataframe is about 50000 x 50000. Is there any simpler method in pandas to filter out the columns with value 0 (and the column with the same name, if it's easy to do)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply to_dict to create dictionary as a value for each row and get series as output,

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[(x!=0) & (x.keys()!=x.name)].to_dict())

cat        {'dog': 0.5, 'dolphin': 0.25}
dog                         {'cat': 0.5}
hamster                 {'dolphin': 0.5}
dolphin    {'cat': 0.25, 'hamster': 0.5}
```

Or you can convert the above series to dictionary with index as keys,

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[(x!=0) & (x.keys()!=x.name)].to_dict()).to_dict()
```

You get,

```
 {'cat': {'dog': 0.5, 'dolphin': 0.25},
 'dog': {'cat': 0.5},
 'hamster': {'dolphin': 0.5},
 'dolphin': {'cat': 0.25, 'hamster': 0.5}}
```

If you get following with `pandas 1.1.2`

```
{0: {'dog': 0.5, 'dolphin': 0.25},
 1: {'cat': 0.5},
 2: {'dolphin': 0.5},
 3: {'cat': 0.25, 'hamster': 0.5}}
```

you can explicitly specify orient parameter

```
df.to_dict('index')
```